# Encrypting and decrypting text file

Tags: c++, file, encryption, text

I wanted to make a program in c++ that will have three options.

1. The user will write a text in the console,this text will be encrypted with some kind of modified xor cipher and the encrypted text will be saved as a text file.
2. A pre existing text file will be imported,encrypted in the same way and the encrypted text will be saved as a text file,like before.
3. An encrypted text file will be imported and will be decrypted and the result will be saved as a text file.

Each time the destination and name of the text file will be entered by the user, i.e. `C:\Users\john\Desktop\` (the backslash needed)
Also the keys for the xor cipher are simply two characters i.e. a, b.
I wrote an algorithm, case 2 doesn't work properly (or works rarely). For example if I have in the file "Hello my name is John!" or something simple it will be encrypted and decrypted properly but if I have copy-pasted some article from the Internet, there is a problem, it doesn't work. It decrypts only some lines of the original text and the rest is random characters/symbols... It must be something with the newline character? I don't know what's wrong.

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int option,choice;
    char temp1,temp2;
    do {
    cout << "Press:\n1.To create text, encrypt it and save it as a text        file\n2.To import text file and encrypt it\n3.To import text file and decrypt it\n\n\n";
    cin >> choice;
    if (choice==1)  {
        string text,coded,directory1,filename1;
        cout << "Enter the text to be encrypted:\n\n\n";
        fflush(stdin);
        getline(cin,text);
        cout << "Enter the two keys for the encryption (two characters):\n";
        cin >> temp1 >> temp2;
        for (int i=0;i<text.size();i++)   {
                coded+=text[i] ^ ((int(temp1)+i)%temp2);
        }
        cout << "The encrypted text message is:\n\n\n" << coded << "\n";
        cout << "Enter the path where the encrypted text will be saved (with \\ at the end):\n";
        fflush(stdin);
        getline(cin,directory1);
        cout << "Enter the name of the text file:\n";
        getline(cin,filename1);
        ofstream data((directory1 + filename1 + ".txt").c_str());
        data << coded << "\n";
        data.close();
    }
    else if (choice==2) {
        string directory1,directory2,filename1,filename2;
        cout << "Enter the path where the file to be encrypted will be imported from:\n";
        fflush(stdin);
        getline(cin,directory1);
        cout << "Enter the name of the text file:\n";
        getline(cin,filename1);
        ifstream data_input((directory1 + filename1 + ".txt").c_str());
        cout << "Enter the two keys for the encryption (two characters):\n";
        cin >> temp1 >> temp2;
        cout << "Enter the path where the encrypted text will be saved (with \\ at the end):\n";
        fflush(stdin);
        getline(cin,directory2);
        cout << "Enter the name of the text file:\n";
        getline(cin,filename2);
        ofstream data_output((directory2 + filename2 + ".txt").c_str());
        cout << "The encrypted text message is:\n\n\n";
        while (!data_input.eof())   {
            string text,coded;
            fflush(stdin);
            getline(data_input,text);
            for (int i=0;i<text.size();i++)   {
                    coded+=text[i] ^ ((int(temp1)+i)%temp2);
            }
            cout << coded << endl;
            data_output << coded << endl;
        }
        data_input.close();
        data_output.close();
    }
    else if (choice==3) {
        string directory1,directory2,filename1,filename2;
        cout << "Enter the path where the encrypted text file will be imported from:\n";
        fflush(stdin);
        getline(cin,directory1);
        cout << "Enter the name of the text file:\n";
        getline(cin,filename1);
        ifstream data_input((directory1 + filename1 + ".txt").c_str());
        cout << "Enter the two keys for the encryption (two characters):\n";
        cin >> temp1 >> temp2;
        cout << "Enter the path where the encrypted text will be saved (with \\ at the end):\n";
        fflush(stdin);
        getline(cin,directory2);
        cout << "Enter the name of the text file:\n";
        getline(cin,filename2);
        ofstream data_output((directory2 + filename2 + ".txt").c_str());
        cout << "The decrypted text message is:\n\n\n";
        while (!data_input.eof())   {
            string coded,decoded;
            fflush(stdin);
            getline(data_input,coded);
            for (int i=0;i<coded.size();i++)   {
                decoded+=coded[i] ^ ((int(temp1)+i)%temp2);
            }
            cout << decoded << endl;;
            data_output << decoded << endl;;
        }
        data_input.close();
        data_output.close();
    }
    cout << "\n\n\nEnter 0 to exit or 1 to return to the main menu..:\n";
    cin >> option;
    } while (option);
    cin.get();
}
```

Oh and I don't have a lot of experience with c++, I started just last year, so don't be hard on me!

Comment: Could you give us an example of text that this code fails to encrypt correctly? The smallest example you can devise, please.

Comment: Alright,for example a random excerpt from a recent bbc news article excerpt:

Many deadly diseases that used to affect millions of children have been largely eradicated or suppressed thanks to vaccinations.
But during times of conflict, such as the war that took place in Bosnia during the 1990s, healthcare is affected and basic childhood vaccinations often are not given.
Today, two decades after the conflict ended, there are more cases of measles in Bosnia than in any other European country.
But, as Guy de Launey reports, getting people vaccinated is easier said than done.

Comment: After the encryption.it is decrypted as:
Many deadly diseases that used to affect millions of children have been largely eradicated or suppressed thanks to vaccinations.But during times of conflict, such as the war that took place in Bosnia during the 1990s, healthcare is affected and basic childhood vaccinations often are not given.Today, two decades after the conflict ended, there are more cases of measles in Bosnia than in any other European c
<Pcb>2m2Uco2vK~SCXWKLWBYDFAuwbb{|y>bwyf~wN
RR{wd6aswz2f~w|2JA\W

Comment: If there were 3 newline characters (vaccinations,not given,European country) the decrypted text would be:
Many deadly diseases that used to affect millions of children have been largely eradicated or suppressed thanks to vaccinations.
But during times of conflict,
UWAVCQRJGYCP

not even close to even the length of the original text..

Comment: You cannot rely on character-oriented tools like `getline` to handle strings composed of `char` values that you have manipulated with bitwise operators. You must either treat the ciphertext as binary data, or restrict the encryption function to ASCII output.

Comment: I see,thank you! I modified my xor code and it works!